# Can this called SALT?

Tags: php, hash, salt

I have the following code

```
$input = 'foo';
$output = hash_hmac('md5', $input, $secretKey);
```

Can the `$secretKey` can be called salt?

Comment: yes, you can call that salt. md5 should be considered cryptographically broken and unsuitable for further use, I would suggest atleast sha2

Comment: I assume that since you are using a hash function (one-way) and care about a salt, you are hashing passwords. For passwords you should absolutely have a look at the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), other hash functions like MD5 and SHA* are ways too fast for hashing passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $secretKey is a salt.

> In cryptography, a salt is random data that is used as an additional input to a one-way function that hashes a password or passphrase. [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)

I would however recommend against using md5, I tend to use sha512 for passwords, and a different salt for each user